# IIS Anonymous user authentication doesn't work with AD credentials

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory, anonymous

I have an asp.net application directory, and I want to use anonymous authentication in the Directory Sercurity tab.

If I use the pre-Windows 2000 style DOMAIN\USERNAME for the username, everything is fine.

If I use the AD-style (UPN) usename@domain.local, then I get a 401.1 failed login.

I've tried a number of variations, but can't get it to work.  If I select the user from the Browse box, the AD name comes up in the box, but the pre-Windows 2000 name is filled-in.  Likewise for SQL Server 2005.

It seems that the UPN isn't 'real', is this right?  Given that it's not required and doesn't have to be unique; it seems very odd.

Am I correct, in that this is not supported?  Would IIS 7 make any difference?

I wish to do this, because the limit of 20 characters for the pre-Windows 2000 username is insufficient for the role-based security I wish to apply for different webservices (the application directories) coming off this website.

Comment: Why does username length make any difference. You're not deriving permisssions from the username.

Answer (score 1):

UPN suffixes should work, althouh there is a bug which occurs when there is a service pack difference between the IIS box and the domain controller.  There is a patch for it.  This [link](http://forums.iis.net/p/1149978/1872165.aspx) discusses the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:**
I have tried it on Windows 2003 sp 2. In the login "directory security" I have checked the enable anonymous access check box ( and only this box ) and put ausername@mydomain.com and the ausername password. The site is plain asp.net without sql backend.

Are you able to login to the server with the usename@domain.local ?
Can you test this on different domain? It may be some wired dns resolution problem.

**Update 0:**

I tested it on iis 6 and the username@domain.com combination works fine on my machine.

About the "realnes" of the names. No name is "real" the actual account is just a GUID. The names are just for convenience.

Comment: Where have you tried it?  I've tried it on several machines in different contexts.  I can use it to run programs, but it will not create a login in SQL Server, or run a website.  SQL Server specifically says it's the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's domain.local and not domain.com. If the domain\username is working, then username@domain.com should work.

Comment: It is domain.local.  It's an internal AD domain.